# Can a Lucio ult counter a McCree ult?

Tags: overwatch

McCree's ult is...complicated. He ramps up potential damage against all targets in his field of view over time. Once he has enough damage ramped up, a skull appears. When he pulls the trigger, he kills all enemies with a skull, and deals damage to all other enemies based on how long they were in his field of view (i.e. how much damage ramped up). Enemies with more health, like Roadhog, take longer to get the "skull" because the damage ramps up slower proportional to his max health.

I get all that.

But how does this interact with Lucio's ult? I've tried to use a Lucio ult to counter a McCree ult in the past, and I'm not sure how effective it was.

How does this work in these situations:

- Lucio and McCree ult at the same time. Everyone gets a huge, but diminishing health pool while McCree ramps up damage. I imagine that this kind of Lucio ult doesn't help much, because by the time McCree fires most of the bonus health is gone anyway. Does McCree lock on "faster" because of the diminishing health?
- McCree ults, and then *just* before he pulls the trigger, Lucio ults. **This is the more interesting case.** Can Lucio "remove" the skull symbol from McCree's locked on targets by ulting and temporarily boosting their health pool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Situation 1**: McCree's lock-on delay for each player is increased proportional to the amount of effective health gained through Lucio's ult. Given that McCree is allowed to use his ult unhindered, you are correct in your assumption that Lucio's ult would do very little.

That said, the delay caused by Sound Barrier is likely to afford your team the time to either prevent him from going through with it or at least to find suitable cover.

**Situation 2**: It is exactly as you have said. In my experience, and as indicated by a player's account of his experience in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/47yzgj/mccrees_ultimate/), increasing a player's effective health removes McCree's lock on effect; however, I am not sure if this resets the delay entirely or if it just increases the delay proportional to the health gained. Either way, it's worth investigation.

In short, Lucio's ult is ***very*** effective at countering Deadeye.

Comment: +1, I can say personally that I've stopped Deadeye from killing *any* of my teammates by using Sound Barrier multiple times.

Comment: Worth noting that as McCree's Deadeye charges lock-on at a rate of 170 health per second, while Lucio's Sound Barrier decays at a rate of 100 per second, it appears as though Deadeye locks on faster, as it is increasing the damage floor by 170 while the ceiling drops by 100.

Comment: That is correct in the case where he is allowed to stand and charge it. But the initial spike in Health will remove the lock-on provided that he has not charged it enough to out-damage the shield.

Answer (score 0):

1. McCree has 6 seconds to pull the trigger while Lucio's ultimate will be fully exhausted in 5 (+500 armor and -100 armor per second).
2. Grudging by [this](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/lucio.html) (where they talk about McCree) Lucio and his teammates will have the upper hand.

Comment: Throw in the fact that if you're dropping the beat in response to the 'High Noon' all, you can bait the lock-in damage, then drop the beat a few seconds in to prevent the McCree from fully locking-in to most targets as he'll have to fire while Sound Barrier is still decaying.